# Does anyone else hate the superuser "mustard" color?

Tags: discussion, color

I find it offensive: squarely in the baby-poo, vomit, etc category.

Edit: I'm referring to the background of the "alert" bar as well as the "welcome" box for not-logged-in users.

Comment: I tried "mustard" as the password - it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: @Aidan: The question, or my comment?

Comment: Well obviously your comment, it's my question.

Comment: D'oh! I was referring to the old "orange" captcha for the blog. Though I actually did try "mustard" to see if it worked. Ha ha only serious, I guess.

Comment: The password is on the blog.

Comment: That colour is called "bogey green", always has been. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I love the SU Colors.

Comment: I love too them. For me its appearance is the best of the three/four sites. The second i like is SO

Comment: Yeah, when I saw superuser I was a bit jealous that SO wasn't styled this way (since I'll probably be on SO the most out of the three sites).

Answer (score 6):

I see mostly blue.

I like blue.

Answer (score 3):

I think the SuperUser colours are way better than Serverfault or Meta.  Ok, Jeff hates Meta, so it gets the ugly scheme.  Fine, I can deal with that.  But Serverfault... blech.  SuperUser has a nice theme IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I like it better than the gray Meta look...

Comment: I think the gray meta rocks... I guess tastes are *very* different in this small world :)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much duplicate of [Thoughts on the new superuser logo and theme?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5380/thoughts-on-the-new-superuser-logo-and-theme).

To answer your question, I think the colour scheme garish, even hideous.

Answer (score 2):

Looks medieval. Try white on white.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like the bubbles around the tag names.  It makes them stand out too much, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

There is one drawback with a blue scheme. Older people, discriminating myself here by giving a specific age boundry at about 40-45, tend to have difficulties distinguishing different shades of blue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean for questions with accepted answer. I find nothing "offensive" about that color.

[image: not poo]